# Magento 2 : When I Create an Order on Admin It Show Disabled Products

Tags: magento2, product, admin, orders, out-of-stock

When I manually create an order in the backend and go to add a product, it will show all products even those out of stock or status disable, is there a hook for this in Magento 2 to hide those products?

There is for Magento 1, but I haven't found one for Magento 2.

Comment: Very Good Question !! expecting good answers from the key/head contributors !!!